# Swift 3.0 code documentation for autocomplete

Tags: swift, autocomplete, swift3, documentation, markdown

I have trouble to document my code to show short description at autocomplete.

My documentation show up in quick help and on ALT+Click, but it doesn't show on autocomplete when I type my function/parameter.

I was looking at official [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/), and I do the same, but it still doesn't show.

Can please someone, who has this figure out for swift 3.0 tell me how he solve it. 
Is there a trick with spaces, new lines,...?

P.S. I try classic "clean project",...

Images :

My documentation :

[image]

Autocomplete :

[image]

Quick help :

[image]